# Sinatra Logging in to Facebook OAuth 2.0 using gem oauth2

Tags: facebook, authentication, rubygems, sinatra, oauth-2.0

I can navigate to the main url which successfuly redirects to facebook.  I grant permission, and I am redirected back to the callback url.  If this url simply returns something like 'hello', it works fine no errors.  But calling `token = client.auth_code.get_token(@data[:code], :redirect_uri => redirect_uri)` causes the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok finally got this to work.  The error being reported was just some weird thing with error handling and had nothing to do with the actual problem.  The problem was that the oauth2 gem is generic and you have to taylor a few things to make it work with facebook.  These are the things you have to do that differ from the readme (see issues 70 and 75 on github for more info)

Before you create your client, you must register a parser for the facebook response:

```
OAuth2::Response.register_parser(:facebook, 'text/plain') do |body|
        token_key, token_value, expiration_key, expiration_value = body.split(/[=&]/)
        {token_key => token_value, expiration_key => expiration_value, :mode => :query, :param_name => 'access_token'}
end
```

You also have to set the token url for the client on creation:

```
  @client = OAuth2::Client.new(ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'], ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET'], {:site => 'https://graph.facebook.com', :token_url => '/oauth/access_token'})
```

When the oauth receives a response, it uses the parser you tell it to use to parse the response into a hash.  The custom :facebook parser ensures that the hash contains the access token and expires string and tells it to use a mode of query and that the param name is access_token.  Without the mode and param_name the Oauth client would attempt to send the access token in a header rather than a query string when accessing resources.  Facebook expects the access token to be in the url.  Without param_name, the oauth client sends it as 
https://graph.facebook.com/bearer_token=ABC.  With the param_name, it is https://graph.facebook.com/access_token=ABC

Finally when you create your AccessToken object, be sure to tell it to use your custom parser like so:

```
token = client.auth_code.get_token(@data[:code], {:redirect_uri => redirect_uri, :parsed => :facebook})
```

Altogether it looks like:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'oauth2'
require 'json'
class App < Sinatra::Base

  configure do
    set :views_folder,  File.join($BP, 'views')
    set :public_folder, File.join($BP, 'public')
  end

  before do
    @data = JSON.parse(request.env["rack.input"].read) if request.request_method =~ /POST|PUT|DELETE/i
    @data = params if request.request_method == 'GET'
  end

  before do
    pass if (request.path_info == '/auth/facebook' || request.path_info == '/auth/facebook/callback')
    redirect to('/auth/facebook') unless self.logged_in
  end

  get "/" do
    request.request_method
  end

  def client
    if !@client
      OAuth2::Response.register_parser(:facebook, 'text/plain') do |body|
        token_key, token_value, expiration_key, expiration_value = body.split(/[=&]/)
        {token_key => token_value, expiration_key => expiration_value, :mode => :query, :param_name => 'access_token'}
      end
      @client = OAuth2::Client.new(ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'], ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET'], {:site => 'https://graph.facebook.com', :token_url => '/oauth/access_token'})
    end
    @client
  end

  get '/auth/facebook' do
    redirect client.auth_code.authorize_url(
      :redirect_uri => redirect_uri,
      :scope => 'email'
    )
  end

  get '/auth/facebook/callback' do
    token = client.auth_code.get_token(@data[:code], {:redirect_uri => redirect_uri, :parsed => :facebook})
    user = token.get('/me').parsed
    create_user user unless user_exists user
  end

  def redirect_uri
    uri = URI.parse(request.url)
    uri.path = '/auth/facebook/callback'
    uri.query = nil
    uri.to_s
  end
end
```

Comment: if anyone sees best practices violations, please let me know im trying to get better at that

Comment: I'd consider grouping your helper methods before the routes, but other than that this looks good to me.  I was about to dive into learning how to do this myself so thanks for puzzling it out for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://rdoc.info/github/intridea/oauth2/OAuth2/Response)  says(and its true) the key is `register_parser(key, mime_types) {|String| ... } ⇒ Object` where key is a descriptive name, not the provider name. If you have to support multiple providers then this approach will break other provider flows as the response format for other strategies would be different